# Unable to customize specflow report with screenshots path

Tags: specflow

I am trying to generate specflow mstestexecution report with the screenshots path mentioned as link. I made use of Console.Writeline() to mention the screenshots path but its getting dispalyed as text in the report. Please provide your inputs on the same.

Comment: please show some code showing what you have done, and what doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The HTML report sees everything as plain text even if you use HTML tags. This is by design. You can change the behaviour of specflow.exe yourself, it is [an open source project on GitHub](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow).

When you don't want to dive to deep into that, you need a more ugly work around: You could consider to tag your links with another token (like {img} instead of ) and than search and replace in the .html file for all {img} to  for example.